# How to store a list of values in Java and retrieve the details

Tags: java

I want to create a list of nodes which stores their name (String), IP(String), port name(Integer), current workload(Integer), and maximum workload(Integer). Tried searching for ways to do this using a hashtable/map or an array list but I only found examples of people using two elements in their lists. Would I be able to retrieve all of these values based on which has the lowest current workload?.

Comment: Well it sounds like you should have a class composed of the name, IP, port, current workload and maximum workload. Then you can create a list of that type...

Comment: Seems good job for PriorityQueue

Answer (score 2):

You can create class `Node` for example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node {

private String name;

private String IP;

private Integer portName;

private Integer currentWorkload;

private Integer maximumWorkload;

public Node (String name, String IP, Integer portName, Integer currentWorkload,
        Integer maximumWorkload) {
    this.name = name;
    this.IP = IP;
    this.portName = portName;
    this.currentWorkload = currentWorkload;
    this.maximumWorkload = maximumWorkload;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getIP() {
    return IP;
}

public void setIP(String iP) {
    IP = iP;
}

public Integer getPortName() {
    return portName;
}

public void setPortName(Integer portName) {
    this.portName = portName;
}

public Integer getCurrentWorkload() {
    return currentWorkload;
}

public void setCurrentWorkload(Integer currentWorkload) {
    this.currentWorkload = currentWorkload;
}

public Integer getMaximumWorkload() {
    return maximumWorkload;
}

public void setMaximumWorkload(Integer maximumWorkload) {
    this.maximumWorkload = maximumWorkload;
}

}
```

And after that adding elements of type `Node` to `List`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    nodes.add(new Node("name1", "0.0.0.0", 111, 1, 3));
    // and you can adds other nodes like this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PriorityQueue<Node>` with custom comparator.